# WPF MVVM add row with two controls to Grid/DataGrid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am studying mvvm and face this problem with dynamic addition - in simple win forms I have done this easily with one loop and just few specification to DataRow..
 So, the task is - to put all elements from List of strings to Grid/DataGrid, that contains two columns - first for check box and second for the string-based control.
I think the best idea is to use DataGrid. So I created a wpf dialog with this DataGrid and buttons and a separate file for ViewModel.
Now my ViewModel class contains a List of strings. 
 And I stuck.. I have read about some `ObservableCollection<UIElement>` that must hold DataGridRow (??) with two controls in my case..

Edit: I am trying  `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn` for check box and  `<DataGridTemplateColumn` for control. So the question now is binding this two columns with a list of strings - pass value of the string to control and all OK.
Need I use an `ObservableCollection` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i am binding a datagrid in wpf using mvvm rather than looking at it as a collection of rows and columns i see it as a collection of objects - each row represents an individual object, and each column represents a property of that object. So in your case, you should make a class to represent what you are showing in your grid, and it will have a boolean and a string property in it (to use in the 2 columns you have stated).

```
public class MyListItem : ImplementPropertyChangedStuff
{
    private string _myString;
    private bool _myBool;

    public MyListItem()
    { }

    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyStringProperty");
        }
    }

    public bool MyBoolProperty
    {
        get { return _myBool; }
        set
        {
            _myBool = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyBoolProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your viewmodel, rather than having separate lists for each column, you can have a single list. If you wish to add/remove/edit rows, then you should use the observable collection, as this has the propertychanged stuff inbuilt and will update the ui when any changes are made to the collection.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   private ObservableCollection<MyListItem> _items;
   public ObservableCollection<MyListItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

 public MyViewModel()
 {
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem>();
    this.LoadMyItems();
 }

 public void LoadMyItems()
 {
    this.Items.Add(new MyListItem { MyBoolProperty = true, MyStringProperty = "Hello" };
 }
}
```

And finally the DataGrid binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyBoolProperty" Binding="{Binding Path=MyBoolProperty}"
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyStringProperty" Binding="{Binding Path=MyStringProperty"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: emybob I have done all you suggested but thie datagrid still empty - I only have initialized Items  as Dennis answered (via get).

Comment: try putting in a basic load method, and add new items to the list in there. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: also, have you got the datacontext on the windows set?

Comment: I have add xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" and <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModell/>
    </Window.DataContext>  But still no data(

Comment: stick a break point on where it adds the item to the collection. If it isn't hitting it, then there's something wrong with the datacontext, if it does hit it then its probably a databinding/raise property changed issue and you should check for any typos etc.

Comment: It hits.. Ok. Thank you once more

Answer (score 1):

You need a view model for data row. Something like this:

```
public class DataRowViewModel
{
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then, instead of `List<string>`, view model for dialog should expose `List<DataRowViewModel>`, or, if you're planning to modify this list from code, `ObservableCollection<DataRowViewModel>`:

```
public class DialogViewModel
{
    // other code here

    public ObservableCollection<DataRowViewModel> DataRows
    {
        get { return dataRows ?? (dataRows = new ObservableCollection<DataRowViewModel>(yourStringList.Select(s => new DataRowViewModel { Text = s }))); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<DataRowViewModel> dataRows;
}
```

Next, setup `DataGrid` to be bound to `DataRows` collection, and bind its columns to `IsChecked` and `Text` respectively.

Note, that for simplicity I've omitted `INPC` implementation in `DataRowViewModel`. This will work, but if you're going to change data row properties from view model's code, you should implement `INPC`.

Comment: I have done all this but my grid still empty - I have used binding as emybob suggested -<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataRows}" but nothing changed.

Comment: And also - could I use a Control type in DataRowViewModel instead of Text propertie?

Comment: why would you want to use a control type? If you're wanting to have a certain control appear in a column and its not one of the standard columns then you use a template column

Comment: @curiousity: You can use everything what you want in data binding scenarios. But since you're learning MVVM, you shouldn't expose any UI elements from view models. One of the goals of MVVM is to separate logic from UI. XAML frameworks use concept of data templates to generate UI elements for view models. About emtpy `DataGrid` - it's not enough information to help you. Are there any binding errors in VS output window? How dialog view model is assigned to window data context?